# Signing out of Hotmail Returns me to MSN Page - Can I change that behaviour

Tags: outlook.com

When I sign out of Gmail, it returns me to the Gmail login screen. When I sign out of Hotmail, it takes me to the MSN screen which is a bit annoying, because, I would then have to do either of the following

1. Type www.hotmail.com in the URL bar
2. Locate Hotmail in the site and click on it to take me back to the login screen

Is there a way that I can change the behaviour of Hotmail so that whenever I sign out, I can be returned to the login screen so that my dad, brother can then login without having to go the whole nine yards?

Comment: Since Hotmail is discontinued, this would appear to be no longer relevant.

Comment: @AlEverett True, but signing out of Outlook.com also returns you to the MSN page.

Comment: Signing out of Outlook.com doesn't put me at the MSN page. Are you signing _in_ from the MSN page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really simple userscript here;

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/4220

That does exactly what you require.

> This script takes you back to the hotmail login page when you sign out from hotmail (instead of that MSN page.)

Hope this helps.